# Merging two datetime-indexed pandas.dataframe objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datetime-indexed pandas.dataframe objects:

object1:

```
 DateTime                     Bid.ESU6  Ask.ESU6
 2016-06-28 08:30:00          207000    207025   
 2016-06-28 08:30:11          206975    207000   
 2016-06-28 08:30:21          207000    207050
```

object2:

```
 DateTime                     Bid.YMU6  Ask.YMU6
 2016-06-28 08:30:00          12793     12795
 2016-06-28 08:30:02          12793     12795
 2016-06-28 08:30:05          12794     12796
 2016-06-28 08:30:08          12793     12794
 2016-06-28 08:30:10          12792     12794
 2016-06-28 08:30:15          12792     12795
 2016-06-28 08:30:22          12794     12797
```

I want to merge these two dataframe objects, but only incorporate the dates from object1. I want to make new columns in object1 that correspond to the closest datetime from object2. In the example above, I would expect to output the following:

```
 DateTime                     Bid.ESU6  Ask.ESU6  Bid.YMU6  Ask.YMU6
 2016-06-28 08:30:00          207000    207025    12793     12795
 2016-06-28 08:30:11          206975    207000    12792     12794
 2016-06-28 08:30:21          207000    207050    12794     12797
```

Is there an easy way to do this without having to make a for-loop going through each row from object1?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: `object1.merge(object2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')` should work

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar: `object1.join(object2, how='left')`, but this gave NaN unless the DateTime was exactly equal in the two objects. I want it to return the elements with the nearest datetimes, rather than the exact datetime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) on `object2` with `method='nearest'` prior to doing the `join`:

```
object1 = object1.join(object2.reindex(object1.index, method='nearest'))
```

The resulting output:

```
                     Bid.ESU6  Ask.ESU6  Bid.YMU6  Ask.YMU6
DateTime                                                   
2016-06-28 08:30:00    207000    207025     12793     12795
2016-06-28 08:30:11    206975    207000     12792     12794
2016-06-28 08:30:21    207000    207050     12794     12797
```